# How to expose template template arg

Tags: c++, templates

Let's assume that I have following class template:
<> - read as template

```
template<template<class T> class Policy>
struct
{

};
```

How (without adding additional params to this <>) can I expose Policy type to external world?
typedef won't work, and why for the loG can't I write something like this:

```
typedef Policy<T> Policy;
```

Why can't I use the T type from << param>>? Is this T type unaccessible?

Comment: This is a job for typedef templates from C++0x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is possible with C++0x, but I don't know the syntax. In the meantime, the closest fit in C++03 is

```
template <template <typename> Pol>
struct Foo
{
    template <typename T>
    struct policy
    {
        typedef Pol<T> type;
    };
};
```

usage: `typename Foo<F>::template policy<T>::type` where you would have wanted to write `Foo::policy<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

The T type is undefined. When you take a template template type, the compiler expects an *incomplete* type that may be instantiated with other type parameters. It doesn't serve to extract the type.

```
template<template<typename T> class X> void func() {
};
func<std::shared_ptr>(); // correct usage
func<std::shared_ptr<int>>(); // fail
```

Comment: Know what you mean by "incomplete type" here, but that's possibly confusing as it properly means a forward-declared type that hasn't been defined yet, an array of unknown size or `void`.  "Template name" perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

As DeadMG said, a template template type is incomplete. For example, the incomplete type std::vector matches `template< template<class, class> class TypeWithTwoParams>`

In order to deduce the actual type of T in your example, you could provide an argument (which has "complete type") to a function. For example, in the code below we can deduce T because we're passing in arg as an argument to PolicyRelatedFunction and it has complete type which allows the compiler to make the necessary deductions.

I get the feeling this is what you're trying to do, except with a function rather than a struct. The typeid stuff is just there to illustrate that we can use T. This will print out "T = std::string"

```
template< template<class > class Policy, typename T>
void PolicyRelatedFunction(Policy<T>& arg)
{
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(int) )
        std::cout << "T = int";
    else if (typeid(T) == typeid(std::string) )
        std::cout << "T = std::string";
}

TemplatedType<std::string> arg;
PolicyRelatedFunction<TemplatedType>(arg);
// PolicyRelatedFunction(arg) works as well - compiler can figure it out.
```